# Let $G$ be a group such that $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ for all $a, b\in G$. Prove that $H=\{x^6\mid x \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Let $G$ be a group such that $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ for all $a, b\in G$. Prove that $H=\{x^6\mid x \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$**

Attempt:

$e=e^6$ i.e $e \in H\neq \phi$

Let $a,b\in H$ then $a=x^6, b=y^6$ for some $x, y\in G$

$$x, y\in G \implies (xy)^3=x^3y^3  \tag 1$$

Now $ab=x^6y^6$

How to show that $ab\in H$ and $a^{-1}=x^{-6}\in H$ using $(1)$.

Comment: Well, $(x^6)^{-1} = (x^{-1})^6$, right? ... How can you rewrite $x^6y^6$ using what you know?

Comment: $(x^6)^{-1} = (x^{-1})^6$ will solve for the 2nd part. Problem is now the 1st part only. Unable to manage the 1st part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, you're interested in dealing with the first part, which I'll show. For $x,y\in G$, $x(yx)^2y = (xy)^3 = x^3 y^3$, hence $(yx)^2 = x^2y^2$ by cancellation. So if $a, b\in H$, say $a = x^6$ and $b = y^6$, then $$ab = x^6y^6 = (x^3)^2(y^3)^2 = (y^3x^3)^2 = [(yx)^3]^2 = (yx)^6\in H.$$