# Let $(G,•)$ be a group in which $(a•b)^3 = a^3•b^3$. Prove that $H=\{x^3 : x \in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $(G,•)$ be a group in which $(a•b)^3 = a^3•b^3$. Prove that $H=\{x^3 : x \in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I assumed a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$ by $f(x) = x^3$. Now $\operatorname{Im}f$ is $H$. This is where I got stuck. How can I show that here $\operatorname{Im}f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$? Please help.

Comment: (Almost) the same question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462958/let-g-be-a-group-such-that-ab3-a3b3-for-all-a-b-in-g-prove-that-h/1462989).

Comment: $g^{-1}x^3g=(g^{-1}xg)^3$

Comment: @Surb No...the kernel of a homomorphism is always normal. The range of a homomorphism is cerainly not necessarily normal! If this was the case then *every* subgroup of *every* group would be normal, as an embedding of $H$ as a subgroup of a group $G$ is simply an injective homomorphism from the abstract group $H$ into $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in H$ so that $a=x^3$ and $b=y^3$. Since $(ab^{-1})=x^{3}y^{-3}=(xy^{-1})^3\in H$, $H$ is a subgroup.

Let $g\in G$. Then $gag^{-1}=gx^3g^{-1}=(gxg^{-1})^3\in H \implies H\lhd G$.